# setTimeout refreshes and milliseconds parameter doesnt work

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

I am trying to run setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true)",2781202000);
```

it should reload page after a month, but somehow it
refreshes immediately in firefox. All similar numbers do same.
Much bigger or smaller milliseconds works just fine and other browsers are working fine too.
(I am using latest version of firefox)

Am i doing something wrong, or is it a know issue?

Comment: Why on earth would anyone keep a page open for a month. It's probably just too long

Comment: well, it work in other browsers and month is not long for some server applications.

Comment: What do you mean "server application", you're saying it refreshes a page in Firefox ?

Comment: And how would you even test this, by opening a page and keeping the browser and computer alive for a month ?

Comment: I have even hosts who didnt switch off their computers for years :) But of course thats rare.

Comment: Not turning of a server for years, and not turning of your browser for years is hardly the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

> Browsers including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox store the delay as a 32-bit signed Integer internally. This causes an Integer overflow when using delays larger than 2147483647, resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.

Comment: to change correct syntax to another correct syntax doesnt solve the problem at all :(

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the problem initially. As soon as I realized it, I deleted my answered, edited it, and reposted. :) My apologies.

Comment: I see. hmm....that might be, but why other browsers doesnt hesitate? Even 9781202000 instead of 2781202000 will work.

Comment: however, thank you for kicking me to the correct path :)